# Need help building regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression to filter out some parts of SQL statements. The statement I currently work with:

```
CREATE TABLE tblname ( 
   column Nr PRIMARY KEY,
   column2 TEXT DEFAULT 'foo',
   column3 TEXT DEFAULT 'foo,bar'
)
```

I want to extract the column definitions from that statement, like this:

```
   column Nr PRIMARY KEY
   column2 TEXT DEFAULT 'foo'
   column3 TEXT DEFAULT 'foo,bar'
```

What I have so far (JavaScript) to remove the `CREATE` part and the last bracket:

```
sql.replace( /^[\w\s]+\(\s+/, "" ).replace( /\s+\)$/, "" );
```

I can't `split()` the string at the comma ocurrences because that's one of the DEFAULT values.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you split on `(` and remove the last character from the second array item?

Comment: Regular expression isn't the way to go.  You need a lexer/parser and an AST.

Comment: If the columns definitions are always on separated lines, you could split by `,\s*[\r\n]`.

Comment: If you are certain you want everything in between the brackets you can do something like this: /\\((.*)\\)/s

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
sql.replace(/^([\w\s]*\()/im, '').replace(/(\)[\w\s]*)$/im, '')
```